# Eclipse proposals(ctrl+Space) needs to be in curly braces

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

```
import java.sql.Driver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class test {

    //{

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.

    //}
}
```

When I am commenting curly braces I am not getting proposals(ctrl+Space) after "driver.", while uncommenting curly braces gives proposals(ctrl+Space). 
Wasted many hours to get this solution, please help me out.

Comment: When the braces are there, it's a valid block of code. When they aren't it's not valid.

Comment: There is no valid continuation, so Eclipse is right. An expression or statement is invalid on class level.

Comment: Could You please, clarify what the exact question is?

Answer (score 0):

This is because it isn't legal syntactically to put a statement inside a class without enclosing it with braces or putting it inside a method.

Nothing strange going on here, just Java syntax rules.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snipper is not part of a method. So without curly braces you are in *Declare Member Mode*. But, while declaring members you cannot invoke any methods on objects (or query any fields).

When placing the code snippet inside the curly braces, you are in fact inside an *initializer block*, where such code is allowed.

Eclipse knows that, and correctly does not provide you any proposals in the first scenario.